# Laravel faker generate gender from name

Tags: php, laravel, faker, laravel-seeding

What is the optimum way of generating gender using faker, having generated a name so that the gender matches the name

```
 return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
    'username' => $faker->userName,
    'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    'gender' => $faker->randomElement(['male', 'female']),//the gender does not match the name as it is.
    'address' => $faker->address,
    'dob' => $faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
    'password' => bcrypt('secret')
    ];
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking at the documentation and an issue raised on the their Github issues section, your solution seems to be the best. Some methods allow you to specify the gender for a name so you could do like this:

```
$gender = $faker->randomElement(['male', 'female']);

return [
    'name' => $faker->name($gender),
    'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
    'username' => $faker->userName,
    'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    'gender' => $gender,
    'address' => $faker->address,
    'dob' => $faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
    'password' => bcrypt('secret')
];
```

Hopefully this fits your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

to do it without additional variable, do it like this

```
return [
  'gender' => $faker->randomElements(['male', 'female']),
  'name' => $faker->name(function (array $user) {return $user['gender'];})
]
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

1. The method *randomElements* is gonna return an array with one single element, so if you want to get 'female' or 'male', don't forget to add at the end of the first line this: **[0]**. You need the first element (index 0) of the resulting array (that only has one element).

   ```
    $gender = $faker->randomElements(['male', 'female'])[0];
   ```
2. One more thing. In order to obtain exactly what you want, you need to use **firstName** instead of name. This way the first name will be according to the gender. Do it this way:

   ```
    return [
        'name' => $faker->firstName($gender),
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'username' => $faker->userName,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'address' => $faker->address,
        'dob' => $faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
        'password' => bcrypt('secret')
    ];
   ```
3. One last thing: If you use 'Male' and 'Female', instead of 'male' and 'female', this is **NOT** gonna work!!

Comment: If that's the case better use getRandomElement to get only one element instead of an array

Answer (score 0):

Actually all answers did not really work for me. It returned female or male only.
I had almost the same issue. I needed a random element out of three genders . It always gave me this error message:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : Array to string conversion (SQL: insert 
 into `users` (`name`, `gender`, `email`, `admin`, `author`, `password`, 
 `remember_token`) values (Margaret Robel I, male, azieme@example.com, 1, 0, 
 dummylogin, gwKdVN7zYv))

 at /Users/mangrove/Desktop/php-workspace/laravel- 
 mangrove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
 660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll 
 format the error
 661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this 
 exception a
 662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the 
 database's errors.
 663|         catch (Exception $e) {
 > 664|             throw new QueryException(
 665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
 666|             );
 667|         }
 668| 

 Exception trace:

 1   ErrorException::("Array to string conversion")
 /Users/mangrove/Desktop/php-workspace/laravel- 

 mangrove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/
 MySqlConnection.php:80

 2   PDOStatement::bindValue()
 /Users/mangrove/Desktop/php-workspace/laravel- 

 mangrove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/
 Database/MySqlConnection.php:80
```

After a look at the documentation for [Faker v.1.8.0](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)

This worked for me:

```
public function run()
{
  $faker = Faker::create();
  foreach(range(1,10) as $index){

    // Returns always random genders according to the name, inclusive mixed !!
    $gender = $faker->randomElement($array = array('male','female','mixed'));

    DB::table('users')->insert([
          'name' => $faker->name($gender),   
          'gender' => $gender,           
          'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
          'admin' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 1),
          'author'=> $faker->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 1),
          'password' => 'dummylogin',
          'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ]);
  }
}

It turns out mixed genders will always have different names, because you can 
be either way ⚧
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine but we can streamline things a bit without having to first set a variable

```
return [
    'first_name' => fn(array $attributes) => fake()->firstName($attributes['gender']),
    'gender' => fake()->randomElement(['male', 'female'])
],
```

As you can see the attribute order doesn't matter either when done this way

Happy coding :)

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#defining-relationships-within-factories

> If the relationship's columns depend on the factory that defines it
> you may assign a closure to an attribute. The closure will receive the
> factory's evaluated attribute array:

Comment: Update: The accepted answer is the way to go especially if you're NOT using state manipulation in your factory. If you use any of the methods in which a closure is used in a needed definitions value seems that the closure is passed to the state function and you won't be able to directly use its values ...unless you call the function (not ideal). A work around could be that you use do your logic in afterCreating or afterMaking